# redirect output of awk gsub command to file

Tags: text-processing, awk

I found an answer on how to remove commas between quotes of a comma delimited csv file over here on stackexchange (cannot comment there as I don't have the needed rep).

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile
```

How can I redirect the output to a file instead of printing it to the console?

I tried various combinations of using '>' which only gave me empty files or errors. '>>' gave me an error every time.

Comment: See [What are the shell's control and redirection operators?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/159513/80216)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the standard redirect will work on standard out:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile > test.out
$
```

This will still print errors to the screen.

However, if you want errors and standard out to go into the file then run:

```
$ awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile 2>&1 > test.out
$
```

Or you can seperate the errors from the standard output:

```
awk -F'"' -v OFS='' '{ for (i=2; i<=NF; i+=2) gsub(",", "", $i) } 1' infile 2> errors.out 1 > test.out
```